# System sound instead of custom sound for push notification plays on quit and background state - Android

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have faced a problem with custom sound on push notifications. I using:

```
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.3.3",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.3.3",
"@types/react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.0",
"react-native": "~0.63.4",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.3",
```

Right now I have a situation that custom sound plays only when the application in the foreground. The default sound is playing for background and closed state of application.

LocalNotificationService.ts

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import {Platform} from "react-native";

class LocalNotificationService {

    configure(onOpenNotification) {
        PushNotification.channelExists(
            'alert',
            (exists) => {
                if (!exists) {
                    PushNotification.createChannel({
                        channelId: 'alert',
                        channelName: 'Alert',
                        channelDescription: 'Alert',
                        vibrate: true,
                        soundName: 'alert',
                    },(created) => alert("Created alert " + created));
                }
            },
        );

        PushNotification.getChannels(channel_ids => {
            alert("channel_ids: " + channel_ids + " len: " + channel_ids.length )
        })

        PushNotification.configure({
            onRegister: (token) => {
                console.log("[LocalNotificationService] onRegister:", token)
            },
            onNotification: (notification) => {
                if (!notification?.data) {
                    return;
                }
                notification.userInteraction = true;
                onOpenNotification(Platform.OS === "ios" ? notification.data.item : notification.data);

                if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData)
                }
            },
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true
            },
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true
        })
    }

    unregister() {
        PushNotification.unregister();
    }

    showNotification(id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) {
        alert("options.soundName = " + options.soundName);
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            ...this.buildAndroidNotification(id, title, message, data, options),
            ...this.buildIOSNotification(id, title, message, data, options),
            title: title || "",
            message: message || "",
            playSound: true,
            soundName: Platform.OS === 'android'
                ? 'alert' //android.resource://com.rnfirebasenotification/raw/alert
                : 'alert.wav',
            userInteraction: false,
            channelId: "alert"

        })
    }

    buildAndroidNotification(id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) {
        return {
            id: id,
            autoCancel: true,
            largeIcon: options.largeIcon || "ic_launcher",
            smallIcon: options.smallIcon || "ic_notification",
            bigText: message || '',
            subText: title || '',
            vibrate: options.vibrate || true,
            vibration: options.vibration || 300,
            priority: options.priority || "max",
            importance: options.importance || "high",
            data: data
        }
    }

    buildIOSNotification(id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) {
        return {
            alertAction: options.alertAction || "view",
            category: options.category || "",
            userInfo: {
                id: id,
                item: data
            }
        }
    }

    cancelAllLocalNotifications() {
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            PushNotificationIOS.removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
        } else {
            PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
        }
    }

    removeDeliveredNotificationById(notificationId) {
        console.log("[LocalNotificationService] removeDeliveredNotificationById", notificationId);
        PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: `${notificationId}`})
    }
}

export const localNotificationService = new LocalNotificationService();
```

FCMService.ts

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import {Platform} from 'react-native'

class FCMService {

    messageListener: () => void;

    register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification) {
        this.checkPermissions(onRegister);
        this.createNotificationListeners(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification);
    }

    async registerAppWithFCM() {
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
            await messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true)
        }
    }

    checkPermissions(onRegister: (token: string) => void) {
        messaging().hasPermission()
            .then(enabled => {
                if (enabled) {
                    this.getToken(onRegister);
                } else {
                    this.requestPermissions(onRegister)
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("[FCMService] Permissions rejected ", error);
            })
    }

    getToken(onRegister: (token: string) => void) {
        messaging().getToken()
            .then(fcmToken => {
                if (fcmToken) {
                    onRegister(fcmToken);
                } else {
                    console.log("[FCMService] User does not have a device token");
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("[FCMService] getToken rejected ", error);
            })
    }

    requestPermissions(onRegister: (token: string) => void) {
        messaging().requestPermission()
            .then(() => {
                this.getToken(onRegister)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("[FCMService] Request Permission rejected ", error);
            })
    }

    deleteToken() {
        console.log("[FCMService] deteleToken ")
        messaging().deleteToken()
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("[FCMService] Delete token error", error);
            })
    }

    createNotificationListeners(onRegister: (token: string) => void, onNotification, onOpenNotification) {
        // App running in background
        messaging()
            .onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
                console.log("[FCMService] onNotificationOpenedApp Notification caused app to open from background state", remoteMessage)
                if(remoteMessage) {
                    const notification = remoteMessage.notification;
                    onOpenNotification(notification);
                    // removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);
                }
            })

        // App is opened from a quit state
        messaging()
            .getInitialNotification()
            .then(remoteMessage => {
                console.log("[FCMService] getInitialNotification Notification caused app to open from quit state", remoteMessage)

                if(remoteMessage) {
                    const notification = remoteMessage.notification;
                    onOpenNotification(notification);
                    // removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);
                }
            })

        // Foreground state message
        this.messageListener = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            if (remoteMessage) {
                let notification = null;
                if(Platform.OS === "ios") {
                    notification = remoteMessage.data.notification
                } else {
                    notification = remoteMessage.notification
                }
                onNotification(notification)
            }
        });

        // Triggered when have new token
        messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
            console.log("[FCMService] New token refresh ", fcmToken)
            onRegister(fcmToken);
        })
    }

    unregister() {
        this.messageListener();
    }
}

export const fcmService = new FCMService();
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import {fcmService} from './services/FCMService'
import {localNotificationService} from "./services/LocalNotificationService";

export default function App() {

  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM()
    fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification)
    localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotification)

    function onRegister(token) {
      console.log("[App] onRegister: ", token)
      setToken(token);
    }

    function onNotification(notify) {
      console.log("[App] onNotification: ", notify)
      const options = {
        soundName: "fire",
        playSound: true
      }
      localNotificationService.showNotification(
          0,
          notify.title,
          notify.body,
          notify,
          options
      )
    }

    function onOpenNotification(notify) {
      console.log("[App] onOpenNotification: ", notify);
      alert("Open Notification: " + notify.body);
    }

    return () => {
      console.log("[App] unRegister");
      fcmService.unregister();
      localNotificationService.unregister();
    }
  })

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Notification token</Text>
        <TextInput value={token} />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

index.js

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import React from "react";
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

import App from './App';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log("Message handled in the background", remoteMessage);
})

function HeadlessCheck({isHeadless}) {
    if(isHeadless) {
        return null;
    }
    return <App />;
}

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(HeadlessCheck);
```

I tried to change soundName value to 'android.resource://com.rnfirebasenotification/raw/alert' but then the sound disappear.

One weird thing is when I open the application I can see 2 alerts: "Created alert false" and "channel_ids:  len: 0". So Channel has not been created. Second weird thing is that on the emulator the channel has been created.

I also tried execute `localNotificationService.showNotification` in `setBackgroundMessageHandler` in index.js.

I pleaced `alert.wav` sound in `android/app/src/main/res/raw/fire.wav`

What did I miss that custom sound for background and close state is the default sound?

Comment: UPDATE: I look more and more at this. The application works on an emulator. All notifications have custom sounds. For some reason, channels don't want to create on a real device(Android 6.0), and this is probably the cause.

Comment: How could you solve this issue @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5753388/sqtr

Answer (score 0):

1. DEFINE A NAME FOR YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL
   It can be anything, and you will use it to target your custom channel from your push message, so that the custom sound you will tie to your channel plays.

I should note that after installing the app the channel name will remain registered until the app is uninstalled. So keep that in mind if you change channel names later.

2. ADD YOUR SOUND AS A RESOURCE
   Drag your .wav sound into the your_project_root/android/app/src/main/res/raw folder (if it doesn’t exist, create it).

ADD THE NOTIFICATION CHANNEL CODE:

First Add All The MainActivity Imports

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
```

The code below must be placed inside the onCreate method of your MainActivity class. Fill in the text surrounded in brackets with your own, and customize anything else you need on your notification:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("my_default_channel", "Tallo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
      notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
      notificationChannel.setDescription("");
      AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
              .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
              .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
              .build();
      notificationChannel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/sample"), att);
      notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
      notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 400});
      notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
      NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
  }
```

Here’s a code example with some values filled in

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("new_email_arrived_channel", "My Emailer", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
          notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
          notificationChannel.setDescription("");
          AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                  .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                  .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                  .build();
          notificationChannel.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/my_custom_sound"), att);
          notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
          notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 400});
          notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
          NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
          manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
      }
```

SET UP THE PUSH BODY
Now that your request is configured, let’s add the push body. This is done in the body tab in the empty area under the data type options. Here is an example body:

```
{
    "to": "<FCM TOKEN>",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Some title",
        "body": "Some body",
        "sound": "my_custom_sound.wav",
        "android_channel_id": "new_email_arrived_channel"
    },
    "data": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high"
}
```